# How to remove epoxy on clothes?

Tags: solubility, solvents, cleaning

**How to remove epoxy on clothes in the perspective of chemistry?**
More precisely in my case, how to remove the **hardener** of epoxy, which consists of two components: hardener and resin.
The clothes is made in nylon, please take the least damage to the cloth into high priorities of consideration.
Does alcohol help?
Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: What hardener - amine, anhydride/amine?

Comment: I have checked. It is unfortunately that it is not listed in the container. But, it is a hardener of a steel epoxy if this information helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lestoil, PineSol or other organic-solvent cleaner should get out the unset hardener. Once set, epoxy is hard to remove; you might try methylene chloride-based paint removers [toxic!]. Some hardeners are organic peroxides, which may bleach spots on the clothing. –

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will try that ASAP and update the result.

Comment: @Superuser Did it help?